# Hide the subfolder from appearing in url

Tags: htaccess, php, 301-redirect, regex

I want to move from `www.example.com/_/randomfolder` to `example.com/randomfolder`.  It should acces the contents from `/_/randomfolder`  but should show `example.com/randomfolder`.

What I have tried:

## Trial 1

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Problem: it full fills my requirement from `/_/randomfolder` but should show `example.com/randomfolder` but affects my main domain `example.com` it shows nothing, only a 404 page.  I want it to show `public_html/index.php` only.

## Trial 2:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#To load site from  /_/xyz to /xyz  without hcanigng url
RewriteRule ^[A-Za-z0-9._]+  /_/%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Problem: I have to manually change the address bar from  `www.example.com/_/randomfolder` to `example.com/randomfolder`, it load contents with or without `_` but on first time load its redirects to `/_/random folder`.

Comment: Why can't you just move the files on your server?  Doing that is usually a lot easier than than messing with rewrite rules.

Comment: Hi its actually a url shortner , i dont want to spam my main public_html

Comment: Does that mean you are creating a file for each shortened URL rather than using a database?

Comment: "I have to manually change the address bar" - by that do we assume you are still linking to the URL that contains `/_`? (Your "Trial 1" doesn't have anything to do with this - that's simply a non-www to www and HTTP to HTTPS canonical redirect?)

Comment: @MrWhite yes but whenever user tries to go to link onclick event ,in new tab he see the _/ in it www.xyz.com/_/random he have to manually remove _/ to which still links ,

Comment: @Stephen Ostermiller♦ yes you are write a random folder with index.php inside it it's like this we.xyz.com/_/randomfolder/index.php

Comment: That approach is not going to be able to support a large number of shortened URLs.   Exactly how many depends of which filesystem your server is running.   On old filesystems, its going to really slow down at around 10,000 created files.  Newer filesystems index the names of the files in large directories which will help lookups and might get you an order of magnitude or two more than that, but you still won't be able to list that directory.   I'd suggest rewriting all the requests to a single PHP file and having that PHP file store the information in a database rather than in the filesystem.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller means it can't be done by httacces ?  from trial 2 its workling like i want , all links are force to go to www.xyz.com/rand correctly but www.xyz.com points to www.xyz.com/_/index.php is there any code for this,

Comment: Mr white has a solution for your question, but I'm saying that your URL shortening site is not going to scale to even a moderate number of shortened URLs unless you change the way it works.

Answer (score 1):

> you are still linking to the URL that contains `/_`?
>   ... yes but whenever user tries to go to link onclick event ,in new tab he see the `_/` in it

Regardless of whether we implement a redirect in `.htaccess` to "fix" this, you do still **need to physically remove the `/_` part from the URLs in the HTML source** that the users click on. Otherwise, they are not "hidden" from the user (they can see them on the page and in the browser's status bar). *Redirecting* these URLs will potentially double the number of requests hitting your server and potentially slow the users' experience.

> ... i dont want to spam my main public_html

Not sure exactly what you mean by "spam", but making the URL appear to be (virtually) in the main directory is really the same as actually being in the main directory - as far as users and search engines are concerned. As far as the local filesystem goes, you still need to avoid conflicts in the same way.

> a random folder with `index.php` inside it it's like this `we.xyz.com/_/randomfolder/index.php`

In that case, you should be rewriting directly to `index.php`, not the directory - which would otherwise require mod_dir to issue an internal subrequest for `index.php`. Also, if you omit the trailing slash then mod_dir would issue an external redirect - which would be undesirable.

Assumptions:

1. `randomfolder` can consist of the following characters only: `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_` (underscore), `-` (hyphen) and `.` (dot). I've only included the dot, as you appear to have included this in your regex, but otherwise you wouldn't necessarily except directories to contain dots. And omitting the dot would simplify the conditions (since you wouldn't need to check that the request does not match a file).
2. A request of the form `/_/<randomfolder/<anything>` strips the trailing `/<anything>` from the request. And redirects to `/<randomfolder>` (no trailing slash).
3. Only requests of the form `/<randomfolder>` (with or without a trailing slash) are rewritten to `/_/<randomfolder>/index.php`. We do not currently check that the destination file exists before rewriting (it would result in a 404 either way).

Try the following:

```
# Redirect requests to remove "/_" from the URL
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^_/([\w.-]+) /$1 [R=302,L]

# Internally rewrite from "/<folder>" to "/_/<folder>/"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w.-]+)/?$ /_/$1/index.php [L]
```

Comment: i tried it , but its its not wroking for me ,i found another solution using javascript lol , here it is :  echo "<script>window.history.pushState('', '', '/mrniamster'); </script>"  , the problem is that when i use a POST or header location on page it doesnt work   idk why i  hope we can fix this up